# Get right FQL query with location_post table

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all posts near specific location. I post some statuces and photos on my FB page with location.
In Graph API Explorer I run this query:

```
SELECT id, coords, type, page_id, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE author_uid = me()
```

and it results in right way, but when I add:

```
SELECT id, coords, type, page_id, timestamp FROM location_post WHERE author_uid = me() AND distance(latitude, longitude, '47', '122') < 10000
```

then all results cleared.

I tried to get distance in query and it results in nice numbers like 33 or 454. So why distance function in WHERE section results in nothing?

Also request from example:

```
SELECT id, page_id
FROM location_post
WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.86564', '-122.25061') < 10000
```

does't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

For the example query, Your lat/long is reported somewhere outside of Oakland, CA. To return data you need one of the following:

- If you requested `user_location` permission in your access token, you need to have made or been tagged in a post made within 10km (~6.25 mi) of this point.
- If you requested `friends_location` permission in your access token, a friend of yours needs to have made this post.

Comment: Yep, I've found out that I can't see people other than my friends. But you missed '-' near 122, it's -122 degrees. And I still can't make distance function() work.

Comment: Yes. The `distance()` function and the whole location table don't work well at all.